# Find the quotient of $A$ by $L$, $A/L$

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

Let $A=\{x \in \mathbb{R} | 0<x<1\}=(0,1)$. Define the relation $L$ on $A$ by $xLy$ if $\left\lfloor {logx} \right\rfloor=\left\lfloor {logy} \right\rfloor$.

I know that $A/L$ is the set of all equivalence classes under the relation $L$.

$[\frac{1}{2}]_L=\{x \in A |\left\lfloor {logx} \right\rfloor\ =\left\lfloor {log\frac{1}2} \right\rfloor\}=\{x \in A | \left\lfloor {logx} \right\rfloor=-1\}$

$[\frac{1}{3}]_L=\{x \in A |\left\lfloor {logx} \right\rfloor=\left\lfloor {log\frac{1}3} \right\rfloor\}=\{x \in A | \left\lfloor {logx} \right\rfloor=-1\}$

$[\frac{1}{10}]_L=\{x\in A|\left\lfloor {logx} \right\rfloor=\left\lfloor {log\frac{1}{10}} \right\rfloor\}=\{x \in A | \left\lfloor {logx} \right\rfloor=-1\}$

$[\frac{1}{100}]_L=\{x\in A|\left\lfloor {logx} \right\rfloor=\left\lfloor {log\frac{1}{100}} \right\rfloor\}=\{x \in A | \left\lfloor {logx} \right\rfloor=-2\}$

We're only allowed to consider real numbers between $0$ and $1$, and $logx$ is the base $10$ logarithm, so that $y=logx$ $\Rightarrow$ $x=10^y$.

I can see there are infinitely many $x's$ for which $x \hspace{1mm} L \hspace{1mm} \left\lfloor {log\frac{1}{2}} \right\rfloor$ and $x \hspace{1mm} L \hspace{1mm} \left\lfloor {log\frac{1}{3}} \right\rfloor$.

I'm thinking the set of all equivalence classes under the relation L is the set containing all the rational numbers between $0$ and $1$? How would you consider the quotient given that every equivalence class has infinitely many elements in it?

Comment: $\log_b$ (base-b log) is the inverse map of the exponential map $x\mapsto b^x$ which is strictly increasing on $\Bbb R$ for $b\gt 1$. The equivalence classes of $A$ under $L$ are then given by $A_k$ which are the open intervals $(b^{-k},b^{-k+1})$ for positive integers $k$, ie, $A/L=\{A_k\mid k\in\Bbb Z_{\ge 1}\}$

Comment: Hint: for each $a \in (0,1)$, there exists a unique $k \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{10^{k+1}} \leq a < \frac{1}{10^k}$. Thus $\lfloor \log a \rfloor=-(k+1)$. So the equivalence class of $a$: $[a]_L=\left[\frac{1}{10^{k+1}}, \frac{1}{10^{k}}\right)$

Comment: Sorry, a bit of typo: the $A_k$ need  to include the lower endpoint, so they are clopen intervals $A_k=[b^{-k},b^{-k+1})$

Comment: @Anurag A How did you get $\lfloor \log a \rfloor=-(k+1)$?

Comment: @Karam We have $\frac{1}{10^{k+1}} \leq a < \frac{1}{10^k}$, so $\log$ being an increasing function implies that  $\log \frac{1}{10^{k+1}} \leq \log a < \log \frac{1}{10^k} \implies -(k+1) \leq \log a < -k$. Thus $\lfloor \log a \rfloor =-(k+1)$.